# how to transform my HTML table to responsive without additional CSS file?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

how to transform my HTML table to responsive without additional CSS file?

```
<table style="overflow-x:auto;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><b>title 1</b></td>
        <td><b>title 2</b></td>
        <td><b>title 3</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text 1</td>
        <td>text 2</td>
        <td>text 3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: well, if you want it to be responsive, you either need to use CSS or Javascript.

Comment: Tables are by nature not responsive. To make a responsive design you need to consider all screen sizes and sometimes move/hide elements from view.

Comment: You can inline the CSS (i.e. not an additional CSS file)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add CSS to make your table responsive, but do not want the CSS to be in a separate file, then you have two options:

1. You can put your CSS rules inside a `<style>` tag in the HTML file ([reference](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_style.asp))
2. You can use inline styles as @Peter suggested. ([reference](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp))

Inline styles can quickly become messy and hard to read, so I would recommend that you use a `<style>` tag.